# Reloading a configuration file under jBoss

Tags: xml, configuration, jboss, seam

Inspired by how Log4j reload its configuration files everytime I change it, I wrote a similar mbean task that read my xml file put in server/(myconfig)/conf

Now I need to access it from my web application, which is in the deploy folder packaged as a .war file (it's a SEAM application).

Should I create a method in the mbean that returns the configuration, or are there any method to share information between mbeans and web application?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I put my configuration object the in the JNDI tree. It works very well.